# Why is agg(np.ptp) slower than pandas agg functions for df aggregates?

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I need to evaluate the range of values in a pandas groupby object; while I didn't find a pandas agg function for this, `agg` happily takes `np.ptp`. The agg [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html#pandas.DataFrame.aggregate) does mention that np by default aggregates over the 2d array, but the timing for `np.ptp` is unchanged when I provide `axis=0` - and the results are the same in any case.
I saw `gdf.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['data1', 'data2'].agg(lambda x: max(x) - min(x))` being ~4x faster than `gdf.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['data1', 'data2'].agg(np.ptp)`.
While I don't mind using the `max - min` method, I'd like to understand if there's any caveats. This is on pandas 0.25, python 3.7.3.